# How to remove after fadeOut of element?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I call `remove` through a JQuery callback. The elements fadeOut successfully, but remove is seemingly not called because `this._id` is not accessible after the fadeOut call?

Refer to the comments in the code below.

```
'click .destroy' : function (){
           console.log(this._id); //This is fine.
    $("#"+this._id).fadeOut('slow',function()  {
           console.log(this._id); //This returns undefined!
           Links.remove({_id:temp}); //Thus this does not work...
     });
}
```

However, when I try to make a copy of the `this._id` variable, and remove by `Links.remove(temp);`, I get: `Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.” Meteor error` since this is client code.

The insecure package is on.

How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the callback for `fadeOut` callback is not the same as the one for the click handler. `this` isn't the same value as you thought it would be. I suggest storing the previous scope's `this` in a variable:

```
'click .destroy' : function (){
  var that = this;
  console.log(that._id);
  $("#"+this._id).fadeOut('slow',function()  {
    console.log(that._id);
  });
}
```

Additionally, code from the client-side, by default, does not allow modifications to a collection. [It's explained below the sample code for `remove`](http://docs.meteor.com/#remove). By the way, "untrusted code" can be thought of as "client-side code".

It's either:

- You do this server-side, so you can do some validation and authentication. Much safer.
- Or just simply allow modification of the collection by doing [`collection.allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a `var that = this` hack, just store the id in the outer closure:

```
'click .destroy' : function (){
    var id = this._id
    $("#"+id).fadeOut('slow',function()  {
        console.log(id);
    });
}
```

I generally view that/self hacks as a last resort; most of the time you can just store one or two variables in the outer closure and it will be much cleaner.